Trying to understand when to use Laplace or Poisson equation
I'm trying to understand in what situations does \$\rho_v = 0\$.
I know that \$\rho_v\$ is zero inside a conductor and non-zero when there is a charge distribution. The book when using has a question regarding finding \$\rho_v\$ from \$V\$ in free space using Poisson's equation and that got me thinking: if there is an eletric field \$E\$ in a region, does that mean that this region has non-zero charge density? I'm confused because there are problems in the book where Laplace's equation is use even though there is an eletric field in the point.
Can we have non-zero eletric fields in a region that is free of charge? When is a region free of charge? (apart from inside a conductor). I'm I wrong because the source of the eletric field is outside the scope of the region I'm using Laplace's equation? Making that \$E \ne 0\$ and \$\rho_v = 0\$?

A good physics book will discuss non-Coulomb electric fields. Also, rather than focusing on B, have a look at the A-field. I'm slowly learning geometric algebra (the applied side of Clifford algebra) and the entire Maxwell equation set is just $\nabla F = J$. And it's not just a terse syntax that doesn't save work. Solving is easier and the perspective is better. See near the end of this video.

Yes, you can have electric field in an area with zero charge density. What you can't have is nonzero electric flux through any surface enclosing zero total charge--I think you may have mixed up a couple of Maxwell's laws here.
